# how to use Hibernate for two different schemas in a single database

Tags: hibernate

I want to use two different schema in database, each schema has same set of Tables but data differs. How to use hibernate and point to two different schema.I am new to the hibernate.Please provide me the links.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

You can specify it by `schema` element while defining table for your entity.

> @Table(name="TABLE_NAME", schema="SCHEMA_NAME")

Else, you can use separate `EntityManager` pointing to respective schema & then use the same entity, as their structure is similar.

---

**Edit :** You can have separate configuration files for each schema & then build `SessionFactory` from it, below is some pseudo-code for it.

```
SessionFactory sf_1 = new  Configuration().configure("schema1config.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
SessionFactory sf_2 = new Configuration().configure("schema2config.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

session_1 = sf_1.openSession();  //-- Similarly for other
```

You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854640/366964) for further details to map multiple schema, but it isn't hibernate specific.

Comment: Using hibernate can we configure two schemas in hibernate.cfg.xml file. I dont want to use JPA. If configurtaion is achieved then, how to query data from each schema separately. Can u post a sample code.

Comment: @shreekanth You can have multiple configuration files, refer edit part for further details.

Comment: can we create one to one between those tables?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar I never tried & never occurred. If these tables are closely related; then they should probably exist in single schema. You can try it yourself; shouldn't take much time.

Answer (score 4):

In your config file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
        <property    name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pwd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">auto </property>
        <mapping class="com.test.db2procedure.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.test.db2procedure.User1"/>
      </session-factory>
     </hibernate-configuration>
```

In your Entity Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SCHEMA.USER") ////Here you can specify your schema name. Here my     schema name is schema
public class User implements Serializable {

private String city;

private String firstname;
enter code here
@Id
@Column(name="ID")
private String id;

private String lastname;

public User() {
}

public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
}
```

For the second class, you have to do this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SCHEMA1.USER") //Here you can specify your schema name. Here my schema name is schema1
 public class User1 implements Serializable {
    private String city;

    private String firstname;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private String id;

    private String lastname;

    public User1() {
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

To test this :

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
         SessionFactory factory ;
         Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
         cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");          
         List<User> user=new ArrayList<User>();
         factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
         Session session = factory.openSession();        
         String hql = "select u2.city from User u1,User1 u2 where u1.id=u2.id";
         Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

         List results = query.list();
         System.out.println("User City: "+results.get(0).toString());
    }
}
```

In the above Test.class execute result set combined from both schema and schema1

Comment: can we create one to one between those tables?

Comment: @Table(name="SCHEMA1.USER") this worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your response, I would like to add one more point to the findings

**Scenario:** Table with same name in two schema

1. The *name* we give in **table** property of @Column annotation
   should match with the name we give in  @Table and @SecondaryTable
   annotation.
2. Hence when we prepend the schema name in @Table, make
   sure we do it in @Column

---

```
@Table(name="schema1.table")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "schema2.table")
})
```

---

```
@Column( name = "col1", table = "schema2.table")
```

---

Note: You don't have to specify table property for the primary table column

Answer (score 2):

From Hibernate 5,use **catalog** instead of **schema** to define schema while creating entity class.

```
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME", catalog="SCHEMA_NAME")
```

Through this case, you can handle multiple schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example (in `hibernate.reveng.xml`):

```
<hibernate-reverse-ingineering>
<schema-selection math-catalog="DataBaseName" />
<table-filter match-schema="FirstSchema" match-name="table-name1" />
<table-filter match-schema="SecondSchema" match-name="table-name2" />
</hibernate-reverse-ingineering>
```