# How to do a foreign key relationship between two tables from different scheme's in Spring JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot 2.2.6 with JPA. I configured two MySQL data sources and configurations with different packages for databases. everything working fine with that.

Now I want to do a relationship(@joinColumn) between two tables which are in a different schema. so when I am doing it, I am getting   **Unknown reference entity exception**.

I researched many places but I dint got the solution to make foreign key relationships between multiple databases.

Is there any solution for this? or it cant be done..?

Comment: Please show us the code you have right now. Also the complete exception, including stack trace.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355358/adding-schema-name-to-entity-in-spring-data

Comment: This might help https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. finally solved it.
First in your entity manager for schema that has the foreign key you should add the packages from both schemas. That way Hibernates is aware of the referenced tables too. Example:

```kotlin
val em = builder
            .dataSource(dataSource1)
            .packages(
                "some.package.schema1",
                "some.package.schema2"
            )
            .persistenceUnit("unit1")
            .build()
```

In my case I need it for a many to one relation. My foreign key in the entity looks like this:

```kotlin
@JoinColumn(name = "other_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
val otherEntity: OtherEntity
```

name and referencedColumnName should match the names in the tables definitions and the foreign key should look like this:

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (other_entity_id) REFERENCES schema2.OtherEntity (id)
```

Both SQL columns should have the same type (BIGINT in my case). And the key in OtherEntity has the annotations @Id and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY). Finally I had a problem when Hibernate was generating querys using only default schema (schema1 in the example). To make Hibernate aware of which schema should use for each table you should add this information to the @Table annotaion in each entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OtherEntity", schema = "schema2", catalog = "schema2")
data class OtherEntity( ... )
```

Initially I had the schema only in schema parameter, later I found that from Hibernate 5, use catalog instead of schema to define schema while creating entity class. Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63561868/13158298

After that it works fine!