# Suggestion between synonyms and separate datsources for two different schemas

Tags: oracle, hibernate, datasource

My Spring/Hibenrnate  applications has to access the tables in two schemas A and B , both of them reside in the same database.What is the best approach?

I have these two things in mind ,if there is a different approach please suggest me.

1) create synonyms for the Schema B -tables in Schema A .Create datasource and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for Schema A alone.

2)Create two set of datasource and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for Schema A and Schema B separately and access them independantly.

Please suggest pros and cons of this .

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach is to use attribute [schema](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#schema%28%29) in Table annotation. It defines schema for entities that are not stored to tables in default schema.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="person")
public class Person {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will be connected to Schema A through datasource A ,  but how will the table Person in Person Schema visible through the datasource A.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Some one else provided JAP approach here
[hibernate mutiple schema mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850213/hibernate-mutiple-schema-mapping/13854640#13854640)